# Is the Vandermonde Matrix Representing an Isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $P_n$ be the vector space of polynomials $p: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with degree at most $n$, and let $t_0, \ldots, t_n$ be $n+1$ distinct real numbers. Define $T: P_n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by $T(p) = (p(t_0), p(t_1), \ldots, p(t_n))$.

1. The first objective is to show that $T$ is an **injective** linear transformation. The hint in the book is given as: Assume that $T(p) = T(q)$. Then $T(p-q) = 0$. This implies that the polynomial $p-q$ has $n+1$ distinct roots. Is this possible? This step is quite straightforward and leads one to conclude that this is indeed impossible because $p$ and $q$ are polynomials of degree at most $n$.
2. The next part, where I do not quite understand the method, aims to show that $T$ is an isomorphism. To accomplish this, we must show that $T$ is,in addition, surjective. That is, every point in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is the image of at least one polynomial $p$ in $P_n$. We can express any polynomial $p$ evaluated at $t_k$ in the form $p(t_k) = 1 + c_0 t_k + \ldots + c_n t_k^n$, where $c_0, \ldots, c_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, we can represent the linear transformation $T(p)$ as a matrix multiplication:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & t_0 & t_0^2 & \cdots & t_0^n \\
1 & t_1 & t_1^2 & \cdots & t_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & t_n & t_n^2 & \cdots & t_n^n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_0 \\
c_1 \\
\vdots \\
c_n
\end{pmatrix}
= T(p)
$$

Our goal would presumably be to show that all the column vectors in this matrix are linearly independent, for this would imply that the matrix multiplication gives a unique solution and thus satisfies the condition for surjectivity. One way to go about this is to show that the determinant of this matrix is nonzero, but this is the part where I do not know how to proceed. It seems obvious that all the column vectors cannot be written as a linear combination of each other, but I cannot prove it. I have read about the Vandermonde determinant and the fact that $$ \text{det}(V) = \prod_{{1 \leq i < j \leq n+1}} (x_j - x_i) $$
is non-zero, is there an intuitive way to understand this concept...?

Comment: You're in finite dimensional linear algebra. Knowing injectivity plus domain and codomain being of the same dimension is enough to show a linear transformation is bijective.

Comment: technical nit since this is algebra: your vector space is that of degree at most $n$ *polynomial functions* not polynomials. Assuming you know rudiments of ring theory: for an intuitive way of directly understanding the non-zero determinant of said Vandermonde matrix, work over $\mathbb F[x]$ and replace $t_n^k$ with $x^k$. By induction hypothesis the leading $n \times n$ principal submatrix is non-zero so $\det(V)$ is a degree $n$ polynomial, with at most $n$ roots, i.e. $t_i$ for $0\leq i \leq n-1$. Thus the substitution homomorphism $\phi:x\mapsto t_n \implies \phi\big(\det(V)\big)\neq 0$.